# Overwriting Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu via module in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've been racking my brain over this for more time than I'd like to admit right now.

### The Aim

Create a module to change the classes that are present in Magento's Topmenu.

### What I've got so far

#### Module Declaration

`app/etc/modules/Issl_Topmenu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Issl_Topmenu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
                <Mage_Page/>
            </depends>
        </Issl_Topmenu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

#### Module Config

`app/code/local/Issl/Topmenu/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Issl_Topmenu>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Issl_Topmenu>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_topmenu>Issl_Topmenu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

#### Class

`app/code/local/Issl/Topmenu/Block/Page/Html/Topmenu.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Topmenu navigation
 *
 * Update classes on the Topmenu navigation to be more in-keeping with style guides.
 *
 * @category   ISSL
 * @package    ISSL_Topmenu
 * @author     ISSL <www.issl.co.uk>
 */

class Issl_Topmenu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu  {
    /**/
}
```

#### Result

Nada. It isn't crashing the page, but it isn't changing the template either. I've confirmed the module is loaded and enabled under `System->Configuration->Advanced` and cache is completely disabled.

The issue is clearly something stupid - where am I going wrong??

Comment: Typo </catalog> should be </page>

Comment: Ah ha. That's fixed, but still having no effect.

Comment: Remove             <topmenu>
                <class>ISSL_Topmenu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu</class>
            </topmenu>

Comment: Only thought is about flushing any and all cache as the final blocker. Put a die( 'here' ); at the top of _getHtml() function in your override to ensure it gets there. If that avails to work try to play around with naming conventions to avoid caps.

Comment: Renamed all instances of 'ISSL' to Issl just in case, but results in the same thing. Module is active and enabled, but even a die doesn't do anything. Clearly for some reason not reading the class.

Comment: Go to your magento root/var folder and delete cache/ and full_page_cache/ Cache being disabled does not mean that your configuration isn't cached.

Comment: Done that before and again just now to be sure, still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73001/discussion-between-vladimir-ramik-and-lewis-howles).

Answer (score 0):

To perform a simple override of an existing base class, simply copy the class to the same path inside the local codepool and do your customizations there:

FROM:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php
```

TO:

```
app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php
```

File:

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
// code..

    public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
    {
// my custom code
```

Always remember to flush cache.

Comment: If possible I'd prefer to avoid this, as it overwrites the whole class, and I only need to change two functions - so I'd miss out on any future updates to the remaining functions.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turned out, the module was working correctly, but modifying Topmenu is a pain and not as simple (any more) as it could be, the function I was using is deprecated and for my purposes, it's probably simpler to create my own template. Many thanks to [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4644312/vladimir-ramik%22Vladimir%22) for helping me get to the bottom of it.